# Strange reference behaviour in C++

Tags: c++

I have fairly short question:

```
vector<int> ints{1,2,3,4};

int &y = ints[0];

// ints.push_back(y);

y = 5;

for (auto &x : ints) {
    cout << x << ", ";
}
```

Why while commented you get `5, 2, 3, 4` but when you uncomment `ints.push_back(y);` you get `1, 2, 3, 4, 1`. I'll write it once more in order to be perfectly clear about the problem: you are getting `[-->1<--], 2, 3, 4, 1`,  instead of `5, 2, 3, 4, 1` or even `5, 2, 3, 4, 5`

This behaviour drives me nuts... What happens under the hood?

Comment: `std::vector:: push_back()` takes a copy, not a reference.

Comment: great, but why does it break reference, I emphasise you get "[-->1<--], 2, 3, 4, 1"

Comment: Undefined behaviour.  push_back can invalidate all references/pointers to contents of the vector.

Comment: this is not they way to use containers ...

Comment: This is typical operation when you iterate through container by reference (since you don't want your large structs/nested vector values to get copied)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you push back onto a vector, if the vector doesn't have enough memory allocated to store the new element, it allocates a new larger memory block, moves the elements over, and frees the old memory. If this happens, any references or pointers to elements of the vector are invalidated.

So, after the push back, when you then assign `5` to `y`, it is undefined behavior, because `y` is an invalid reference, and there is no reason to expect the assignment to have any effect on any elements of the vector.

Comment: @Lu4 Well, it´s clearly stated [in the standard and some reference sites and ...] that references may break when inserting...

Answer (score 4):

You need to consider the reallocation that might happen when `std::vector::push_back` is called.

```
int &y = ints[0];

ints.push_back(y);

y = 5;
```

The third instructions may cause undefined behavior if such reallocation is performed. If that happens, you lose all the guarantees you could think of.
Taking out this condition, by `reserv`ing memory, the expected result is shown

> 5, 2, 3, 4, 1,

```
std::vector<int> ints{1,2,3,4};
ints.reserve(128); // Note

int &y = ints[0];

ints.push_back(y);

y = 5;
```

The table at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) shows what happens precisely and when iterators are invalidated.

Usually, you don't want to have free references or pointers to elements stored in a container that could be invalidated; if that's truly needed, reload the address or choose a container that offers more guarantees about reallocation  such as `std::deque`, `std::forward_list` or `std::list`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are pushing back a copy. The reason is that your vector holds type int not type &int so it implicitly casts the reference by making a dereference copy.

In the example where push_back is commented out you have not added your copy to the end of the vector and still have a reference pointing to the first element, meaning you can alter the element through the reference. However once you do the push_back the vector is resized and the objects within it moved, invalidating any references or pointers to those objects.

You can see this clearly by simply making your vector set to a larger size when it is constructed. i.e.

```
vector<int> ints(5);
ints = {1,2,3,4};

int &y = ints[0];

ints.push_back(y);

y = 5;

for (auto &x : ints) {
    cout << x << ", ";
}

// output = 5,2,3,4,1
```

Comment: Your second sentence is difficult to understand

Comment: Edited for clarity. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't change the second sentence... (starting "The reason is")